# move packages to bottom in IntelliJ Project view structure

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: 1]

Is it possible to move rest-api package under files (in red rectangle's place)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives similar result:

Check **Sort by Type** then 
Uncheck **Folders always on top**

[image]